# How to apply a REGEX to an entire column in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Say for example in `column C` I have all emails which contain the same domain. This field is populated by a form.

I need a function to remove the `@domain.com` from the field every time a new record is inserted in the column.

pseudo code:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(<this-cell-value>,"@domain.com","")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming your data starts in row 2, in D2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(C2:C, "(.+)@")))
```

This should extract from col C everything that is before the @.

See if that works ?

Comment: Yes this works .. Is it possible to do the regex within the C col so that I do not have to create another col?

Comment: No, you can't have the output in the same column that is referenced by the formula. What you can do is, copy the output (in col D) then paste it in col C (choose paste special > values only).

Comment: yeah thats what I ended up doing.. Thanks!